# How to find "STEAM only" Counter-Strike 1.6 and Source servers?

Tags: steam, counter-strike, counter-strike-source

Both games are good, though I love 1.6 better.

One thing ruins all the gameplay. Non-steam players (more than 70% of them are cheating.)
They can't be banned, can't be checked.

Is there a way to find STEAM ONLY servers? Original, non-cracked, with VAC... I mean.
I have tried Xfire, Game-arena, with not much luck. (Only searching for "Steam" in the name of the servers.)

I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Why not just look for VAC-enabled servers?

Comment: Because cracked servers are VAC enabled. It may seem stupid, but the crack enables VAC, yet allows non-steam people to join.

Answer (score 5):

In the server menu is an option to search for VAC-secured servers
There are NO official steam servers, There are only induvidual gamers and communities who run these.

Just looking for VAC secured servers should be enough to prevent having to deal with hackers.
Othwerwise consider joining a community that has some good servers (I will not name any)
Most bigger communities have admins on at most times and when you stick around them you might find some guys/gals who are great to hang around with.

Also consider that some people aren't actually hacking alltough I would allways accuse them of doing so, CS is one of these games where some people just developed insane skills

Comment: The "VAC flag" is ON on almost 99% of the servers. However, it lets all people join, and if you are a non-steam user, you get NO check by VAC. VAC won't see you on the server. That's why, filtering by VAC doesn't work. (SADLY!)

Comment: Well then use the last option.. find a good community that has secured their server with more then VAC and primarily has an admin on most of the time. Honestly, I have no problem finding servers without hacking, I wonder why you do...

Comment: Well, I'll give one upvote for every comment containing a good server.

Comment: Check out the "family" servers. They have some of the best communities and do a really good job policing for hacks.