# Does the original Counter-Strike have "official" servers?

Tags: counter-strike

Does CS have official Valve servers as CS: Global Offensive? When searching for servers I find countless community servers using custom game modes (I can't change 'game' filter), sounds, textures and rules.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/how-to-find-steam-only-counter-strike-1-6-and-source-servers

Comment: If I recall correctly from my days of playing Half-Life and CS the answer is no and yes. Specifically, gamers had to host there own game servers but, to my knowledge, you had to connect your service to Valve (and eventually Steam) so that others could discover your server. Of course users had the option to share server IPs with one another but if you wanted to go global, you had to connect it to Valve's servers. To be clear, Valve didn't host any games but they did host the connecting/server searching system.

Comment: I say this to make it clear. If you install an old ISO, there is a good chance you won't be able to discover any games, including your own from a personal hosting server but I could be wrong on that assumption. Valve could still have those old updating servers running that would automatically patch your game so that it can connect up to the latest steam servers, even after a decade of it's initial release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it never had official servers, as they never hosted any sort of Match Making or anything close to that prior to Global Offensive.

Any and all servers in CSSource and older are all community servers.

I figured the best way to receive proper experience is to find a big gaming chain that hosts many (and most likely different servers) A local site hosted like 20 servers when I was playing with them, there were admins, reporting the whole 9 yards.

Comment: Is there a way to disable all custom content?

Comment: @user598527 I don't think so, your best bet is to look for "Classic" or something similar in the title.