# How to disable downloading custom files in multiplayer?

Tags: goldsrc-engine

GoldSrc games such as Counter-Strike, Half-Life and Day of Defeat [don't have official servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291557/does-the-original-counter-strike-have-official-servers) and servers running custom content can't be segregated in the server browser. Community servers can run "total conversion" game modes, custom maps and use entirely their own textures and sound effects, including music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cl_allowdownload 0` console command (see key bindings).

[image: download cancelled]

`cl_download_ingame 0` command disables downloading files from joining players, this [appears to be limited to](http://steamcommunity.com/app/70/discussions/0/527273983050519789/#c527273983051360469) "[sprays](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Spray_(logo))" (a custom image that can be placed on a surface).